# error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to NumPal

Tags: java, constructor, program-entry-point

I've read many threads on this issue and most seem to be resolved by fixing the main method. However, part of the assignment is we cannot alter NumPalDrvier.
How else can I fix this issue, as I dont fully understand it?

This is the given main code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class NumPalDriver {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    String start = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number: ");
    System.out.println("start value ["+ start + "]");
    NumPal p = new NumPal(start);
    int ctr = 0;
    while (!p.pal() && (ctr < 10)){
      System.out.println(p.toString());
      System.out.print("new sum: ");
      System.out.println(p.getCur()+" + "+p.getRev()+ " = " +
                         (p.getCur()+p.getRev() ));
      p = p.next();
      ctr++;
    }
    System.out.println("final value: " + p.getCur());
    System.out.println("number of steps: " + ctr);
  }
}
```

My code which makes the main possible:

```
public class NumPal{ //header

private long numRev; //initializes variables
private long numCur;
private String stringRev;
private String stringCur;

public NumPal(String stringCur){//constructor
this.stringCur = stringCur;
}

public boolean pal(){

   if (stringCur == stringRev){
      return true;}
   else {
     return false;}
     }

public String reverseString (String input){ //creates reverse version of string
   int length = input.length();
   String stringRev = "";
   for(int j = 0; j <= length; j++){
      stringRev = input.charAt(j) + stringRev; 
      }return stringRev;
      }

public void next(){ //where the error is
   stringRev = reverseString(stringCur);
   numRev = Long.parseLong(stringRev);
   numCur = Long.parseLong(stringCur);
   numCur = numCur + numRev;
   stringCur = Long.toString(numCur);
   }

public String getCur(){ // returns current string
   return stringCur;
   }

public String getRev(){ // returns reverse string
   return stringRev;
   }
}
```

If someone could break down what this error means it would be really appreciated!

Comment: Can you share a stack trace?

Comment: Ive tried googling what a stack trace is and im not quite sure how to do that sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Following line on your NumPalDriver

```
p = p.next();
```

Expects your next() method in NumPal class to return a NumPal object (or null). Current code returning nothing. Rewrite it to return a NumPal

I.e:

```
public NumPal next(){ 
    // return a NumPal, possibly following
    // existing code of this method goes here
    return new NumPal(stringCur)
}
```

Comment: Ah, I understand now, thank you,

How would I go about manipulating the object in the method however?

Comment: If you want to manipulate current object add following to end of next() method  [ this.stringCur = stringCur; return this; ]

Comment: Yes I figured it out. Thanks for your help, my understanding of returning objects was completely wrong, but I completely get it now.